# Add new sharer to the camera roll

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this. The goal is to add a new sharing option to the camera roll sharing actions (see the attached screenshot). This option have to open my application with a given image or video as a parameter of a method.

[image: An example of what I would like to do]

Is it possible to do this? If yes, it will be great if you can show me snippets for achieving this.

Cheers!

Cyril

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible with the current iOS SDK.

Comment: Seems legit. I didn't found any way to subscribe to some "list of sharing handler". Cheers.